# Seeking Method to Log Spreadsheet access to SQL Server 2008 database

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

How can I log who is using Excel to access a SQL Server 2008 database?

While I can see users Hostname that are using Microsoft Office to access the database (using `SP_who2` and other custom scripts), I wish to log this access over a period of time. Ideally also see the queries that are being run.

I have been given the task to try to determine what spreadsheets and people are accessing the database with Excel and am unsure how to do this over the period of a day. Only at a moment in time.

Comment: What have you try so far ?

Comment: I am currently running a script that grabs the Session ID,  SQL being used Login_name Host and DB. Im running this every 5 mins and putting result into table. I have run this for a few hours so far. This is OK but I'm sure I'm missing some of the spreadsheets that are accessing the DB.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I have used an SP called sp_whoisactive [enter link description here](http://whoisactive.com)

I have used this to write to a table every 5 minutes. I have added a filter on program and program name 'Microsoft Office%'